# Found nil in JSON YouTube API just for the videoId

Tags: ios, swift

So I'm writing an app that uses the YouTube API:

```
func callAlamo(url: String) {
    Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON(completionHandler: {
        response in
        self.parseData(JSONData: response.data!)
    })
}

 func parseData(JSONData: Data) {
    do {
        let readableJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: JSONData, options: .mutableContainers) as! [String: AnyObject]
        if let items = readableJSON["items"] {
            for i in 0..<items.count {
                // other code here
                let item = items[i] as! [String: AnyObject]
                let id = item["id"] as! [String: AnyObject]
                let videoId = id["videoId"] as! String //here it founds nil
                self.videoIds.append(videoId)
                // other code here as well
            }
        }
        tableView.reloadData()
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

For other things like thumbnails, titles and descriptions it works very well, however here it founds nil. Yes, I know what nil is. I've studied the JSON response but can't figure out why it gives me the error.

The JSON: https://pastebin.com/HXsqxLyv

Comment: Please provide us JSON data.

Comment: @user7861999 Show your json data structure.

Comment: Updated with JSON data.

Comment: Instead of posting a link to the entire JSON file, please copy and paste just a relevant section of it into your question.

Comment: Look at your JSON line 1005... there's no "videoId". Don't force unwrap your optionals: instead, handle the possible errors.

Comment: @EricAya, yes, you're right...thank you!